# Dovecot ACL Configuration

Tags: imap, dovecot, roundcube, directadmin

The following is what i am trying to achieve: 
users are allowed to move email between folders, but not fully delete the message.

Using the dovecot ACL:

```
user=arjo@xxx.nl lrwsip
```

This translates to: 
Lookup, Read, Write, Write-seen, Insert, Post

In a sense, because i dont have the T flag, (Write-Deleted) means that nothing  is allowt to be deleted.

Roundcube works somewhat okay, it does not allow me to delete a message. However, it does not allow me to move a message. (which i do want to do)

Outlook does move the messages, but it can not delete them. This makes it so that it creates the messages in the new folder, but they stay behind in the old folder. (it makes a copy).

What should i do to make this function properly?

System setup: 
Centos 7
Directadmin 1.5
Dovecot/exim

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off topic for SO.  You may be able to get assistance on our sister site for server admins, serverfault.

Comment: However some knowledge: in basic IMAP move is implemented by doing a COPY then a DELETE.   Even if dovecot implements the move extension and the client uses it, it may be considered internally a move, then delete.  Therefore, disallowing delete may not allow a move to occur.